# dGrid keeps scrolling left and setting keepScrollPosition to true does not seem to work

Tags: scroll, dojo, position, esri, dgrid

I am using a featureTable dgrid from Esri's API. It is essentially a dojo onDemandGrid. Whenever I scroll to the right of the grid and click on any cell or row, the grid always scrolls all the way back to the left of the start position. I know there is a boolean 'keepScrollPosition' property within the grid object.

```
    **doesn't work**
    this.featureTable.grid.refresh({ keepScrollPosition: true }); 

    **sets keepScrollPosition to 'true' but still continues to scroll back left when cell or row is clicked**
    this.featureTable.grid.set({ keepScrollPosition: true }); 

    **I tried setting the keepScrollPosition at the grid instance but doesn't seem to be working either**
    this.featureTable = new FeatureTable({
                featureLayer: this.featureLayer,
                map: this.initData.mapController.map,
                columns: this._getColumns(this.featureLayer),
                grid: { keepScrollPosition: true }      
            }, "qr" + e.item.id);
```

I've gone through a lot of forums and done some extensive research and can't seem to get the grid to retain it's scroll position. I've even tried manually setting the {x,y} scroll positions every time the grid is rendered but it seems to always refresh, clear, and reset it's scroll position. I believe this might be a bug within dojo, but if someone can show me a solution to this scroll issue, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Could you create a fiddle that shows this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem.
First, I think the way you assign "grid: { keepScrollPosition: true }" is not valid. Second, I haven't seen *any* way to set this property that *is* valid.  I think Esri does not give access to this feature.

My hacky workaround was to do this:

```
featureTable.grid.on(".dgrid-header .dgrid-cell:click", _headerClicked); 

function _headerClicked(event){
    var scroller = $(".MyContainerClassName .dgrid-scroller");
    if (scroller.length) {
        scroller = scroller[0];
        var oldscrollpos = scroller.scrollLeft;
        scroller.onscroll = function (evt) {
            console.log("oldscrollpos:", oldscrollpos);
            scroller.scrollLeft = oldscrollpos;
            scroller.onscroll = null;// disable this callback so user can go back to real scrolling
        }
    }
}
```

I should add, in my case the scrolling only happens when the user sorts on a column, so here the scroll-fix is only invoked by clicking on a column header. It sounds like you would need to trigger it on more events than just that.